# Is it correct to say "fall in a mistake.."?

Tags: phrase-usage

I described a mistake and then I wanted to say that I made that mistake when I started my project. "I think *I fell in this mistake* when I started my current project", I said. Isn't this expression awkward?

Comment: I don't understand the expression "I think I fell in this mistake when I started my current project." I also am not sure what exactly you want to say by it.  Rather than just describing the situation, could you first use words that you believe to be correct, and then offer an equivalent with the words you are not sure of?"  In that way, we might be more helpful in guiding you in how to express yourself correctly.

Comment: It is not correct to say "fall (or fell) in a mistake". It is correct to say, "I fell into this mistake when I..."

Comment: @FeliniusRex That is an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not idiomatic to talk about falling into a mistake.

The usual expression is simply "make a mistake".

The iWeb corpus has only 37 instances of "fall into a/the mistake" and 2 of "fall in the mistake", against 17844 instances of "make a mistake".

Comment: Right, but you can fall in with the wrong crowd.

Comment: We also "fall into bad habits" or "into a rut."  Those are common expressions that might lead someone to extend the metaphor to "falling into a mistake"; however, that is not a common collocation.

Comment: We can also _fall into error_, but much less likely to _fall into **an** error_. Go figure.